# Android : How to create this layout dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a layout dynamically in android which consist some buttons. But I am unable to find any way to dynamically create this layout.

Here is my layout :

[image: Dynamic Layout]

I want to put buttons into next line after they completely filled in the width of device. Total number of buttons can be varied. 
Is there any way to do this dynamically?

**UPDATE :**
As per your suggestions I'm using this code :

```
private void addQuestionPallete() {
        int tempBtn = 30;
        LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.1f);
        LayoutParams param2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1f);

        linearContent.setWeightSum(1f);
        linearContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        btnQuestionPalete = new Button[10];

        for (int j = 0; j < tempBtn / 10; j++) {
            linearQuestionPalettesRow = new LinearLayout(mContext);
            linearQuestionPalettesRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            linearQuestionPalettesRow.setLayoutParams(param2);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                btnQuestionPalete[i] = new Button(mContext);
                btnQuestionPalete[i].setLayoutParams(param);
                btnQuestionPalete[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                btnQuestionPalete[i].setText("5");
                btnQuestionPalete[i].setId(fChexkBoxID++);
                linearQuestionPalettesRow.addView(btnQuestionPalete[i]);
            }
        }
        linearContent.addView(linearQuestionPalettesRow);
    }
```

but its only showing single row of buttons. Where I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE :**

OK I have solved my problem. I was adding layout out of for loop. thus the layout is adding only one time.

Comment: yes whats you have tried? Otherwise Take button and add in horizontal linear layout.

Comment: I tried to add in Horizontal linear layout but how to put them in next line after they reach at the maximum width of screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add a Horizontal Linear Layout in a Vertical Linear Layout.
- Set the "weight sum" of the Horizontal Linear Layout to 1.
- Now before adding the buttons, set each button's weight to 0.1
- Keep a counter for the numbers of buttons added starting from 1 and when it reaches 10, add another horizontal Linear Layout.

You can change the weight of the buttons as you like, making them larger or smaller and then adjust your counter to behave accordingly.

For e.g., if you decide to assign weight = 0.2 to each button, then your counter should count till 5 (1/0.2 = 5). You can also set the weight as 0.05 or 0.025 etc. depending upon the number of buttons you want in each row.

This way you need not worry about the different screen sizes because the weight property will adjust the views in any screen size.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Vertical Linear Layout
2. Add a horizontal Linear Layout to the vertical Linear Layout
3. Then add buttons to the horizontal Linear Layout using the `addView` method
4. Keep a count of the buttons and when it reaches the max repeat from step 2

Comment: I thought about this but how to find if the buttons filled the complete width of screen?

Comment: You can calculate that based on the screen size and size of each button. So from that you can easily set the max number of rows

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have more control on how system places your object on the screen i suggest you to implement your custom layout.

You should create a class that extends ViewGroup and override the methods:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
```

and

protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4)

In this method you describe how your object has to be placed on the screen. For example if your object has all the same sizes you can calc the distance from the left side and the distance from top side like this:

```
int left = pinImg.getCol() * dotSize + dotSize ;
int top = pinImg.getRow()  * dotSize + dotSize ;
```

where pinImg is in this case the object to place.

In your xml describing your layout you had

```
<package.CustomView
     android:id="@+id/pinsTable"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"    

    />
```

Hope this help.